# Как добавить правильно заполнять RecyclerView, используя SwipeToRefresh?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Добрый день. Понимаю, что вопрос очень детский, но я никак не могу разобраться с этим. У меня есть `RecyclerView` с CardView-вьюхами). `RecyclerView` я заполняю данными через `AsyncTask1` при первом переходе. Я добавил к `RecyclewView` `SwipeRefreshLayout` и хочу добавлять сверху новые элементы. Для этого использую AsyncTask2. Но новые данные заполняются не сверху старых, а после них в списке. Подскажите, как их отображать "над" старыми. Ниже код добавления данных. Всё лишнее поубирал. в `IncomeTask` происходит первичное заполнение адаптера. Во второй таске уже подгружается доп. данные. Еще раз повторюсь, код работает, но список заполняется "под" уже существующим. Понимаю, что нужно что-то поменять в последних методах в моём коде. Пробовал циклом присваивать в новом массив старые данные + новые, но это очень долго происходит.

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

            IncomeTask incomeTask = new IncomeTask(new AnotherCallback() {
                @Override
                public void myTaskDone() {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ГОТОВО", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    fillArray();
                    fillRv();
                }
            });
            incomeTask.execute();
                          }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.income_rv);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
        mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.swipe_container);

        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                if (checkDB()){

                    counter += myPage;
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Наш коутер = " + counter);
                    UploadPageTask uploadPageTask = new UploadPageTask(new AnotherCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void myTaskDone() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ГОТОВО", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                 fillUpArray();
                              //  fillRv();
                                counter++;
                            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Наш обновленный коунтер = " + counter);

                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                        }
                    });
                    uploadPageTask.execute();
                }           

            }
        });

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore saved layout manager type.
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }

        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);


             mRecyclerView.setPadding(0, 110, 0, 0);

        return rootView;
    }


    public void fillArray(){
        incomeMssg = IncomeTask.incomeArray;
        incomePrice = IncomeTask.tenderPrice;

    }

    public void fillRv(){
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(incomeMssg, incomePrice );
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mRecyclerView.setPadding(0, 110, 0, 0);
    }
    public void fillUpArray(){
       incomeMssg = UploadPageTask.incomeArray;
        incomePrice = IncomeTask.tenderPrice;
        mAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(incomeMssg, incomePrice );     
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В адаптере должен использоваться список (`ArrayList` например) данных.
2. Когда вы хотите его изменить - надо в него добавить/заменить данные.
3. После этого надо уведомить адаптер о изменении данных (`notifyDataSetChanged()` или `notifyItemRangeChanged(int from, int to)`)
4. Создавать новый адаптер при изменении данных не нужно - надо изменить данные в текущем.
5. Хранить данные в публичных статических переменных к-л класса - плохая идея.

Судя по всему у вас проблема в том месте, где вы новые данные добавляете в существующий их список.

Comment: Почему плохая идея? Я к ним обращаюсь из других классов, поэтому требуется static.

Comment: @Denis422, с архитектурной точки зрения плохо это. Я, конечно, не знаю деталей вашей задачи, но обычно использование такого подхода говорит о неверной архитектуре.